# Laravel Controller does not recognise an instance class function

Tags: php, laravel

I created class which load DB data.

```
   <?php

namespace App\Repositories;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class FantasticRepository
{
        public function getFantastic($id)
        {
            $user = Auth::user();
            $companyId = $user->id;
            $tableName = "elites";
            return \DB::table($tableName )->where('id', $id)->first();
       }

}
```

But a controller can not call a function of the class I created.

```
use App\Repositories\FantasticRepository;

class FooController extends Controller
{
    private FantasticRepository $fantasticRepository;
    public function getFantastic(Request $request)
    {

       $ke = $fantasticRepository->getInformation($request->id);
      return view('ke.index',compact($ke));
    }
     public function getInformation($id){
        $ko = \DB::connection('second')->table("pens" )->where('user_id', $id)->first();

      return view('ko.index',compact($ko));
}

   }
```

My Error log says

> local.ERROR: Undefined variable: fantasticRepository {"userId":4,"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Undefined variable: fantasticRepository at /Users/Developments/abc/app/Http/Controllers/FooController.php:36)
> [stacktrace]
> #0 /Users/Developments/app/Http/Controllers/FooController.php(36): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError(8, 'Undefined varia...', '/Users/...', 36, Array)

Is a laravel app able to use an external class?

[image]

Comment: use correct method `use App\Repositories\FantasticRepository;

class FooController extends Controller
{
    use FantasticRepository;
    public function getFantastic(Request $request)
    {

       $ke = $this->getFantastic($request->id);
      return view('ke.index',compact($ke));
    }
   }`

Answer (score 1):

in Laravel we can import call with use.

```
use App\Repositories\FantasticRepository;
class FooController extends Controller 
{     
   use FantasticRepository;     
   
   public function getFantastic(Request $request)     
   {         
        $ke = $this->getFantastic($request->id);
        return view('ke.index',compact($ke));     
   }    
}
```

Comment: I don't want to use trait , having the same name function in FooController.

Answer (score 0):

You need dependency injection. You can do that on constructor or in function argumants.

```
public function __construct(private FantasticRepository $fantasticRepository) {}

//or

public function getFantastic(Request $request, FantasticRepository $fantasticRepository) {}
```

Comment: I tried both. However, nothing changed.

Comment: Did you read error message you added recantly. It says "unexpected private." So it is a synax error, which means it's not about class and you don't use PHP 8. You need to define your constructor older way or update your PHP version. If another error pops up we can look at it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the `private` function outside of its class
so you have to define  `getFantastic` function as `public` function to use it in controller

```
 private function getFantastic($id)
        {
            $user = Auth::user();
            $companyId = $user->id;
            $tableName = "elites";
            return \DB::table($tableName )->where('id', $id)->first();
       }
```

to

```
 public function getFantastic($id)
        {
            $user = Auth::user();
            $companyId = $user->id;
            $tableName = "elites";
            return \DB::table($tableName )->where('id', $id)->first();
       }
```

Comment: I changed it from private to public. However, the same error still happen.